# Unexpected string constant in R when try to select colname from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I try to group by my customize movieLense dataset

```
groupBy<- data.table(unifiedTbl)    
x<- groupBy[,list(rating=sum(rating)
    ,Unknown=sum(unknown)
    ,Action=sum(Action)
    ,Adventure = sum(Adventure)
    ,Animation = sum(Animation)
    ,"Children's" = sum(Children's)
    ),by=list(user_id,age,occupation)]
```

but because of **Children's** I received some error which related to specified character
If I remove below part of my code every things is OK

```
,"Children's" = sum(Children's)
```

Now my question is how can I address to this column with full name?
how can I fix my codes?

Comment: Not tested, try with backquote maybe `.

Comment: @Pascal I couldn't change my columns original names, because I need them further

Comment: It is not my suggestion.

Comment: @CathG name() was good suggestion thanx but I got this error when using it 'Error in sum(names(groupBy)[7]) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument'

Comment: If you want only the sum of each column, use `.SD` and `.SDcols`: `groupBy[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=list(user_id,age,occupation),.SDcols=c("rating","unknown","Action","Adventure","Animation","Children's")]`

Comment: the name was for the left part, in the sum, I suggested using `get`: `"Children's"=sum(get("Children's"))` works. But anyway, @nicola suggestion is way better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use backticks with names that aren't valid syntax:

```
`Children's` = sum(`Children's`)
```

And of course, I'd recommend creating valid names instead:

```
setnames(groupBy, make.names(names(groupBy)))
```

Comment: @Pascal thanks for your suggestion too pascal But I didn't get what you mean

Comment: @WhizDeveloper you should really get used to using `lapply(.SD,sum)` instead. You need to read some `data.table` intros IMO